# How do I know whether std::hash is implemented in terms of std::identity?

Tags: c++, hash, unordered-map, c++20

I want to write my own unordered container and would need to know whether i can store key/value pairs or if -when hash and key differ- i need hash/key/value tuples. To that end, i need to know at compile time whether `std::hash<K>` returns the value untouched.

C++20 seems to define `std::identity` but even then I'm not sure if i will be able to do something like this (which i doubt):

```
if (std::hash<K>() == std::identity<K>())
```

Clang-7, which is what i'm working with, uses a bunch of template specializations to define its identity hashes. Is there a better solution?

Comment: Not sure if I read it correctly, but I am not sure if your approach is viable. What if user gives you their own hasher? How would you know if it returns identity or not?

Comment: It's too bad they didn't make that a member of `std::hash` that we could query.

Comment: `std::hash` isn't even required to be `constexpr`

Comment: @NathanOliver again, the problem is, hasher can be anything - and it can be a non-class, so they couldn't mandate the hasher to expose certain members.

Comment: @SergeyA They could have made that requirement.  They did for `std::shuffle`.

Comment: `std::identity<T>` is **a** function object that returns its argument; there’s never any kind of requirement that it have any relationship with **another object** that happens to do so.

Comment: @NathanOliver not sure I follow - random generator for shuffle can be anything that is callable. It doesn't have to expose any members AFAIK. They have requirement on it's return type, but not an anything else.

Comment: @SergeyA Unfortunately that is no longer true.  `shuffle` requires that the generator is a [UniformRandomBitGenerator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/UniformRandomBitGeneratorb) which is required to have 4 specific members.  You can't use a lambda or function portably with `shuffle` like you could with `random_shuffle`.  That could have done the same thing with the hasher for the unordered containers.

Comment: @NathanOliver you are correct, I didn't know! On any rate I personally am not sure if I would support that. Also, it would be somewhat at odds with `std::map` interface.

Comment: I'd do otherwise. Instead of checking if hash is identity or not - I'd specialize your hash-map for cases when identity is a hash.